# How can I sum 2 positive and 1 negative float issue

Tags: ios, iphone, math

I have some issue when calculating 3 CGFloats

I have:  -34.522 + 39.049 + 0.2889 = ios gives me 73

but it should give me more like aproximative to an normal calculator values like = 4.81

```
CGFloat x = (46.2076 * -34.522) + (60.3827 * 39.049) + (2.028 * 0.2889);
NSLog(@"d %f",x); ->>  763.291199
```

Comment: Show the actual code you're using.

Comment: Hey dude I have tried this it is working .     NSLog(@"%.2f",-34.522 + 39.049 + 0.2889);

Comment: It calculate same as normal calculator. Show you code.

Comment: CGFloat h  = -34.522 + 39.049 + 0.2889;
    NSLog(@"%f",h); LOg IS ====>> 4.815900

Comment: ive edited my question with code

Comment: so what is wrong in it.? it gives right value that is 763.291199

Comment: i added new code, what my NSLog is with what im tryng to calculate and result is not what is expected

Comment: Yes, but normal calculator doing same calc is giving  4.81
i cant see where the issue is

Comment: `-34.522 + 39.049 + 0.2889` and `(46.2076 * -34.522) + (60.3827 * 39.049) + (2.028 * 0.2889)` are two completely different calculations. Why do you expect to get the same result?

Comment: Martin could you help me to resolve second one ?
(46.2076 * -34.522) + (60.3827 * 39.049) + (2.028 * 0.2889)
it seems i understood it wrong

Comment: Your code gives the correct result 763.291199. What result do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat t = -34.522 + 39.049 + 0.2889;
NSLog(@"%f",t);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're asking, but if you only want 2 digits of precision, you have to specify this. It's easy to do via format specifier by using `%.2f` where 2 is the number of digits after the decimal place to be shown.

```
CGFloat x = (46.2076 * -34.522) + (60.3827 * 39.049) + (2.028 * 0.2889);
NSLog(@"d %.2f",x);
```

Alternatively, this can also be done with `NSNumberFormatter`.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];

[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"#.##"];
NSString *output = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(x)];

NSLog(@"Out: %@",output);
```